# Swift Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift

When I try to launch my app, I have two errors which looks to be internal breakpoints, but I am unable to remove them the error message is: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` These are the lines of code receiving the errors(I can provide the whole view controller if needed):

```
Interest(title: "We Love Traveling Around the World", description: "We love backpack and adventures! We walked to Antartica yesterday, and camped with some cute pinguines, and talked about this wonderful app idea. ⛺️✨", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "r1")!),
```

and

```
private var interests = Interest.createInterests()
```

EDIT: Code for interest:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController
{
    // MARK: - IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var currentUserProfileImageButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentUserFullNameButton: UIButton!

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
    private var interests = Interest.createInterests()

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    private struct Storyboard {
        static let CellIdentifier = "Interest Cell"
    }
}

extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return interests.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestCollectionViewCell

        cell.interest = self.interests[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
}

extension HomeViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
    {
        let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing

        var offset = targetContentOffset.memory
        let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing
        let roundedIndex = round(index)

        offset = CGPoint(x: roundedIndex * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        targetContentOffset.memory = offset
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put the code of `Interest` ?

Comment: Can you try to set other params to `Interest` `init` method? And are you sure that you have image with `r1` name?

Comment: And add code of `Interest` class.

Comment: The `UIImage(named: "r1")!` part is suspicious. Make sure the image initialization doesn't fail, by first assigning it to a local variable and passing that variable as the value of `featuredImage:`. This way you can step and see if it is `nil`.

Comment: Although, I think in this case you should get the error message: "Found nil while unwrapping an optional".

Comment: I believe I found the error, I just changed up UIImage(named: "r1")! It looks to run fine now, thank you for your help on tracking down this error. If one of you could create like an answer of some sort so I can answer this question, thanks. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have no image with `r1` name. And when you try to unwrape it with `UIImage(named: "r1")!`, app is crash. Try to check that the object `UIImage` is created before passing it to the `init` of `Interest`